# Problems with Erf for large arguments with small imaginary part

Tags: numerics, special-functions

While performing some higher precision calculation, I noticed that Mathematica 12.1 killed the kernel and cleared all prior definitions. The problem was with `Erf` for large arguments (with small imaginary part). I ran this on MacOS (10.14.6):

```
GL = 10^-3; sG = 10^-6;
N[Erf[(3 + I GL)/sG], 32]
```

It gave this messages

> ...is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost

and killed the kernel.

I tried it on a Win10 laptop and it ran out of memory.

`Erf = 1 - Erfc` is a quick fix (or hack).

Is this a problem with `Erf` in Mathematica 12.1?

Another problem which occurs for `Erfc` is:

```
GL24 = N[GL, 24]

Erfc[(3 + I GL24)/sG]

1 - Erfc[(3 + I GL24)/sG]
```

The last line is also a problem.

Comment: With Windows 10 and 12.0, I got a `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]`, which is pretty wild. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: The killing of the kernel does not seem normal to me: report that to WRI support. However, the fact that numerical evaluation of `Erf` may underflow for large parameters is specifically indicated in its documentation ("Possible Issues") so it is expected behavior and it is the reason why `Erfc` is available.

Comment: Windows 10 and the 12.1.1 update also has `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]` but the kernel doesn't get killed.

Comment: SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"] means memory is exhausted. It not unusual for complex problems to run out of memory. A **frequent** result of memory exhaustion is kernel death. Kernel death cause all defiinitions to disappear. I often quit the kernel to assure that all definitions are gone.